# How to resolve "specified origin access identity does not exist or is not valid"

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a problem with these lines in my `serverless.yml` file. 
I am using the Serverless plugin `serverless-single-page-app-plugin`.

```
# CustomOriginConfig:
              #  HTTPPort: 80
              #  HTTPSPort: 443
              # OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
              ## In case you want to restrict the bucket access use S3OriginConfig and remove CustomOriginConfig
              S3OriginConfig:
                 OriginAccessIdentity: origin-access-identity/cloudfront/E127EXAMPLE51Z
```

I want use `s3OriginConfig` and disable access through the S3 bucket. I can do this manually. But I want to get the effect as in the picture below:

[image: AWS Console config]

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You might have solved it as you have asked your question long back but this might help if you didn't. I too faced the same issue and after some research through AWS documentation, I got to know how to use the required attributes. Below points to be considered regarding your question.

1. As your origin is Amazon S3 bucket, you should use **S3OriginConfig** in Distribution.
2. If new OAI is required then you have to create a **CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity** resource and refer the OAI and  *S3CanonicalUserId* attribute to the **CloudFront Distribution** and **S3BucketPolicy** resources respectively.

Please find the below snippet in response to your question.

```
WebAppDistribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
          - DomainName: 'passport-front.s3.amazonaws.com'
            Id: 'WebApp'
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity: !Join ['', ['origin-access-identity/cloudfront/', !Ref CloudFrontOAI]]
CloudFrontOAI:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
    Properties:
      CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
        Comment: 'access-identity-passport-front.s3.amazonaws.com'
WebAppBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: "Retain"
    Properties:
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      BucketName: "passport-front"
WebAppBucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref WebAppBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Action: s3:GetObject
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            CanonicalUser: !GetAtt CloudFrontOAI.S3CanonicalUserId
          Resource: !Join ['', ['arn:aws:s3:::', !Ref 'WebAppBucket', /*]]
```

> References: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-cloudfront.html

Comment: If the S3 bucket is being used a static website, you have to use "CustomOriginConfig" which then begs the question - how do we associate the OAI with the distribution?

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps. OAIs are now deprecated in favor of Origin Access Controls (OAC). If you use an OAC, you still have to specify S3OriginConfig but you put an empty string for the OAI value. The following is a valid DistributionConfig for a non-website s3 bucket:

```java
            String bucketWebsiteEndpoint = String.format("%s.s3.%s.amazonaws.com", bucketName, bucketRegion.toLowerCase());
            List<String> distributionAliases = prepareDistributionAliases(domainName, subDomainName);
            // Create CloudFront distribution configuration
            DistributionConfig distributionConfig = new DistributionConfig()
                    .withAliases(new Aliases().withItems(distributionAliases).withQuantity(distributionAliases.size()))
                    .withCallerReference(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())) // Unique reference
                    .withComment("CloudFront distribution for " + domainName)
                    .withDefaultCacheBehavior(new DefaultCacheBehavior()
                            .withTargetOriginId(bucketWebsiteEndpoint)
                            .withViewerProtocolPolicy(ViewerProtocolPolicy.AllowAll)
                            .withAllowedMethods(
                                    new AllowedMethods()
                                            .withQuantity(2)
                                            .withItems(Method.GET, Method.HEAD)
                                            .withCachedMethods(
                                                    new CachedMethods()
                                                            .withQuantity(2)
                                                            .withItems(Method.GET, Method.HEAD)
                                            )
                            )
                            .withForwardedValues(
                                    new ForwardedValues()
                                            .withQueryString(true)
                                            .withCookies(new CookiePreference().withForward("none")))
                            .withViewerProtocolPolicy(ViewerProtocolPolicy.RedirectToHttps)
                            .withMinTTL(0L)
                            .withDefaultTTL(86400L) // 1 day
                            .withMaxTTL(31536000L) // 1 year
                    )
                    .withEnabled(true)
                    .withPriceClass(PriceClass.PriceClass_All)
                    .withViewerCertificate(
                            new ViewerCertificate()
                                    .withACMCertificateArn(certificateArn)
                                    .withMinimumProtocolVersion(MinimumProtocolVersion.TLSv12_2021)
                                    .withSSLSupportMethod(SSLSupportMethod.SniOnly))
                    .withOrigins(new Origins()
                            .withItems(
                                    new Origin()
                                            .withId(bucketWebsiteEndpoint)
                                            .withDomainName(bucketWebsiteEndpoint)
                                            .withConnectionAttempts(3)
                                            .withConnectionTimeout(10)
                                            .withS3OriginConfig(new S3OriginConfig().withOriginAccessIdentity(""))
                                            .withOriginAccessControlId(accessControlId)

                            ) // Use the bucket's endpoint
                            .withQuantity(1));
            CreateDistributionRequest createDistributionRequest = new CreateDistributionRequest()
                    .withDistributionConfig(distributionConfig);
            
            // Create CloudFront distribution
            CreateDistributionResult createDistributionResult = cloudFrontClient.createDistribution(createDistributionRequest);
```

And this is how you would create the OAC:

```java
            String bucketWebsiteEndpoint = String.format("%s.s3.%s.amazonaws.com", bucketName, bucketRegion.toLowerCase());
            // create origin access control
            CreateOriginAccessControlRequest createOriginAccessControlRequest = new CreateOriginAccessControlRequest()
                    .withOriginAccessControlConfig(
                            new OriginAccessControlConfig()
                                    .withOriginAccessControlOriginType(OriginAccessControlOriginTypes.S3)
                                    .withName(bucketWebsiteEndpoint)
                                    .withDescription("Origin access control for " + bucketWebsiteEndpoint)
                                    .withSigningBehavior(OriginAccessControlSigningBehaviors.Always)
                                    .withSigningProtocol(OriginAccessControlSigningProtocols.Sigv4)
                    );
            CreateOriginAccessControlResult result = cloudFrontClient.createOriginAccessControl(createOriginAccessControlRequest);
```